# How to submit a form object that contains more objects to Spring to create a DTO that has multiple other DTOs

Tags: java, jquery, spring, dto

I have a form with fields that overall is designed to represent a software tool. In our vision, a tool has a name and description, a release object, and 1 to many authors. A version has a release date and version number while an author has a name.

My goal is to take this form and submit it to Spring where it will be transformed into a corresponding DTO to be further manipulated.

My code so far:

ToolDto.java

```
public class ToolDto {
    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    private String name;

    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    private String description;

    @NotNull
    private VersionDto version;

    @NotNull
    private List<PersonDto> people;

    // getters and setters...
}
```

VersionDto.java

```
public class VersionDto {
    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    private String versionNumber;

    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    private Date releaseDate;

    // getters and setters...
}
```

PersonDto.java

```
public class PersonDto {
    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    private String name;

    // getters and setters...
}
```

Controller.java

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/tool")
public class Controller {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<String> createTool(@ModelAttribute("toolForm") @Valid ToolDto toolDto, BindingResult result, WebRequest request, Errors errors) throws JsonProcessingException {
        if (!result.hasErrors()) {
            // good responce
        }
        else {
            // bad responce
        }

        return responce;
    }
}
```

The form

```
<form id="toolForm">
    <label>Tool name:</label>
    <input id="name" name="name" type="text" value="" />

    <label>Description:</label>
    <textarea id="description" name="description" /></textarea>

    <label>Initial version number:</label>
    <input id="versionNumber" name="versionNumber" type="text" value="" />

    <label>Initial version release date:</label>
    <input id="releaseDate" name="releaseDate" type="date" value="" />

    <div class="person">
        <label>Author name:</label>
        <input class="personName" type="text" value="" />
    </div>
    <button type="button" id="personButton">Add another author</button>

    <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Finally, the js code that submits the form

```
var version = new Object();
version.versionNumber = $("#versionNumber").val();
version.releaseDate = $("#releaseDate").val();

var people = new Array();
$.each($(".person"), function() {
    var $this = $(this);

    var person = new Object();
    person.name= $this.find(".personName").val();

    people.push(person);
});

var tool = new Object();
tool.name = $("#name").val();
tool.description = $("#description").val();
tool.version = version;
tool.people = people;

$.ajax({
    url: "/tool/",
    type: "POST",
    data: $.param(tool)
}).done(function (data) {
    console.log("yay!");
});
```

My problem is that as long as the ToolDto contains other DTOs, it doesn't work. Deleting the version and people DTOs from ToolDto works just fine, however I need those and deleting them isn't an option.

Specifically the error I get is:

```
org.springframework.beans.InvalidPropertyException: Invalid property 'people[0][name]' of bean class [-----.dataTransferObjects.ToolDto]: Property referenced in indexed property path 'people[0][name]' is neither an array nor a List nor a Map; returned value was [-----.dataTransferObjects.PersonDto@25bc7fae]
```

Or if I remove just the PersonDTO from ToolDto I get the same error, only about VersionDto.